# Detect whether user has access to Files/photos from browser using Javascript in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, photo, mobile-browser

I would like to detect whether a user has access to Files/Photos when the user selects a file from `<input type="file">`. In mobile browser, if user has denied the photos access then nothing happens when we click the file input. In this case, I would like to alert the user that you do not have permission to access photos.

Is there any way to reliably detect if permission to access Files/Photos is currently allowed in a browser using Javascript?

I have tried [Permission API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) and [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) but it does not help as it only gives you camera permission and also it is not reliable.